# Recursive Prefix-Sums K times

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recursion

I have been wondering about the following question for quite some time:

You are given an array $x$. Define f(x) as the prefix sums of this array.

For example, f([1,0,1]) = [1,1,2] and f(f([1,0,1])) = [1,2,4].

Define $k$ to be the recursive depths of a series of f(x) (how many times it is nested).

For example, f(f(x)) has $k$ = 2, and f(f(f(f(x)))) has $k$ = 4.

Given an array $x$, calculate f(x) with $k$ depth.

Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well I didn't get stuck anywhere. This is more of a theoretical question that I came up with myself. It's not (to my knowledge) on any site or in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution will take $O(nK)$ time where $n$ is length of array. Just repeat $K$ iterations over the array.

But you can be clever if $K$ is large. View this as a matrix multiplication.
The matrix will be just lower triangular with all entries one.

Now matrix multiplication is associative, so you can take product of matrix multiplications even before you know the array.

Furthermore, you don't need to naively take product of matrices $K$ times, just use the idea of repeated squaring.